# Android - Load and save bitmap without increase destination file size

Tags: android, bitmap, save

I have a problem in saving images in my app.

The process is simple:

1 - I read the image into a bitmap for display

2 - Save the bitmap as a new file

At this point, I do not understand why the final file has a size much larger than the original image. For example, a 170 kb image is saved in a new file 1 mb.

I know the difference in the management of compression between PNG and JPG, but I expect that if I read a PNG file, and save it in the same format, the size remains the same.

Thank you all for the help.

**Edit**

This is my code for saving method:

```
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(original, generateWidth, generateHeight, false);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempResizedFile.getPath());
                            resized.compress(generateType.CompressFormat(),
qualityBar.getProgress(), out);
out.close();
```

Comment: post you code here for better answer.

Comment: generateWidth, generateHeight size and image Width, Height ?

Comment: generateWidth, generateHeight are same values of width and height read from orignal image. I open a 1280x1024 png image into a bitmap, then save this bitmap to another file, same size, same format.

Comment: @MicheleZiparo maybe you could just save the original input filestream?

Comment: @danny117 I need to make some changes before saving, but I thought the size was greater guilt of my actions, instead reading and saving without change, the size increases without reason.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.CompressFormat.html maybe you could compress the output with the compressFormat method.